# Stored procedure to get paged sorted results with a computed data column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, search, sorting, stored-procedures

I want to make a stored procedure to get paged sorted result but here's the twist. I have to add a column and fill it with computed/calculated data. Currently I have

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[pr_GetPagedSortedOrdersByUser]      
(
 @userid numeric(18,0),              
 @CurrentPage int,              
 @PageSize int,            
 @SortField varchar(200),            
 @SortOrder varchar(5),        
 @status varchar(50)        
)              
as              
begin              
with temp as              
  (              
   select * 
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by            
        CASE WHEN @SortField = 'orderdate' AND @SortOrder = 'Desc' THEN orderdate END DESC,            
        CASE WHEN @SortField = 'orderdate' THEN orderdate END,      
        CASE WHEN @SortField = 'netamount' AND @SortOrder = 'Desc' THEN netamount END DESC,            
        CASE WHEN @SortField = 'netamount' THEN netamount END,      
        CASE WHEN @SortField = 'id' AND @SortOrder = 'Desc' THEN id END DESC,            
        CASE WHEN @SortField = 'id' THEN id END                       
       ) AS ROWID              
   from tbOrder    
   where (@status='All' or delivered=@status)and userid=@userid

  )              
  select * ,
  (
    netamount - discount
  ) as 'Gross'     
   from temp             
  where rowid>((@CurrentPage - 1) * @PageSize) and rowid <(@CurrentPage * @PageSize + 1)              

  select count(*) as [count]            
   from tbOrder    
   where (delivered=@status or @status='All')and userid=@userid       
end
```

**NOTE:** `Gross` column is not present in database and I should be able to pass value `Gross` to `@SortField`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to add your computed column into your case statement to sort by it:

```
select * 
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by            
        CASE WHEN @SortField = 'orderdate' AND @SortOrder = 'Desc' THEN orderdate END DESC,            
        CASE WHEN @SortField = 'orderdate' THEN orderdate END,      
        CASE WHEN @SortField = 'netamount' AND @SortOrder = 'Desc' THEN netamount END DESC,            
        CASE WHEN @SortField = 'netamount' THEN netamount END,      
        CASE WHEN @SortField = 'id' AND @SortOrder = 'Desc' THEN id END DESC,            
        CASE WHEN @SortField = 'id' THEN id END,
        CASE WHEN @SortField = 'gross' AND @SortOrder = 'Desc' THEN netamount - discount END DESC,            
        CASE WHEN @SortField = 'gross' THEN netamount - discount END   
       ) AS ROWID              
   from tbOrder
```